# How to call an index

Tags: arrays

I'm new here so I don't really know if there's a standard way to interact.

I have started learning javascript and I'm at a point where i learn about indexes and how to call them. The thing is, i was given an example without a full explanation of it.

The array is like this :

```
var myArray = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [ 7, 8, 9 ], [ [10, 11, 12], 13, 14, ] ];
```

I am trying to call the number 10 from the array which logically should be with the index `[3][0]` but if I call it that way, I receive numbers 10 and 11, 12 which I don't want. I don't really understand what's happening on the second half of the array and i also didn't get an explanation regarding how to specifically call the number 10 in there. Anyone who can make things more clear for me?

From what I can understand, `[10, 11, 12]` is one index but what if I want to call the number 10? I was thinking of calling a negative index but I've lost my hope after finding out there is no way.

Thanks

Comment: `myArray[3][0][0]`

Comment: Are you sure about the empty last element (after `14, `)? JavaScript does allow for array element elision, but it seems odd to introduce it in a beginner's JavaScript course or tutorial.

Comment: that was my mistake, corrected it. thanks so much

Comment: Your question is very unclear. You write "I am trying to call the number 10 from the array", but that is impossible: you can only call functions in JavaScript, and the number 10 is not a function, it is a number, so you simply *cannot* call it.

Comment: are you sure i cannot? because i've just tried calling the number ten with myArray[3][0][0] and it worked.

Comment: I am very sure that you cannot call numbers in JavaScript. You can only call functions. See [section 7.3.13 *Call(F, V [, argumentsList\])*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-call) and [section 7.2.3 *IsCallable(argument)*](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-iscallable) of the [ECMAScript Language Specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/).